# Adding Image in Run Time

Tags: wpf, image

I want to add an image from my Resources to an `Image` on the press of a `Button`.

Using `Image1.Source = Properties.Resources.MyImage` Does not work because the `Image1` is of type `ImageSource` and the Left side is of type `Drawing`. How can I fix this code to display the image in my resource to the `Image` on button press?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

In app.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Image x:Key="myImage" Source="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

in MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid x:Name="myGrid" Margin="5" Width="500">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Load Picture" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        <Image x:Name="ImageHolder"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

in button click event:

```
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Image img = Application.Current.Resources["myImage"] as Image;
        ImageHolder.Source = img.Source;
    }
```

So in your code you need to do :

```
Image myImage = Properties.Resources.MyImage as Image;
Image1.Source = myImage.Source;
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that `Properties.Resources.MyImage` is already an image so you don't have to cast it again ...